# NodeJS : Value for shared state of module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going through the tutorials of [nodejs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo7IRCjrxMk&index=10&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_) and while learning about the shared state of module, i come through few doubts :

i have written this code :

Sparsh.js

```
var popcorn = require('./popcorn');
popcorn.favPopCorn = 'cheese';
console.log(popcorn.favPopCorn);
```

Ravi.js

```
var popcorn = require('./popcorn');
console.log(popcorn.favPopCorn);
```

app.js

```
require('./Ravi');
require('./Sparsh');
require('./Ravi');
```

popcorn.js

```
module.exports = {
    printRate : function() {

        console.log('popcorn rate');
    },
    favPopCorn : ''
};
```

output
      (blank)
cheese
      (blank)

As per the output the firstblank is considerable as we didn't assign any value to favPopCorn.But after i assign the value to favPopCorn in Sparsh.js.It should print 'cheese' while we again use require('.\Ravi.js'); as it is a shared state.

Please help

Comment: variable popcorn is reinitialized in ravi.js everytime you require ravi.js

Comment: So the output is correct as per the variable scope.

Comment: as per the tutorials , it is a shared state so when we change it in Sparsh.js the value of favPopCorn should reflect in Ravi.js

Comment: However i checked that again , we can use "require('anymodule')" only once , so adding require('./Ravi'); doesn't make much sense

Comment: You have to remove "var" from variable declaration to make it shared by putting it in globals

Answer (score 1):

`Ravi.js` is *also* shared (well, "cached" is a better word), so it's loaded just once (the first time). The second time, Node knows that it was already loaded and doesn't load (/execute) it a second time (it doesn't output a blank, it doesn't output *at all*).

A common method to work around that is to export a function:

```
// Ravi.js
var popcorn = require('./popcorn');

module.exports = function() {
  console.log(popcorn.favPopCorn);
}

// Sparsh.js
var popcorn = require('./popcorn');

module.exports = function() {
  popcorn.favPopCorn = 'cheese';
  console.log(popcorn.favPopCorn);
}

// app.js
require('./Ravi')();
require('./Sparsh')();
require('./Ravi')();
```

Comment: yeah you are right , but can you tell me the way so that it should reflect the modified value.

Answer (score 1):

A clean pattern for this kind of think is to create an object with `new` in your shared module:

```
//popcorn.js

function popcorn(){
    this.printRate = function() {
        console.log('popcorn rate');
    }
    this.favPopCorn = "" 
}

module.exports = new popcorn()
```

Now when you get and set the `favPopCorn` property in other modules, you will be manipulating a singleton.